# want to implement a rotatation of images list interface using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

Actually i have a list 6 div elements and each div contains some images and two buttons.
my question is how can we select the list of images for each instance of div using javascript.
All the div's are having the same class name and all the images are having the same class name.
I tried querySelector but it selects only one instance and the same event doesn't run for the other div's
querySelectorAll selects all the div's so unable to execute the event for a particular image inside the div

I want to get this result, when the right button inside the div is clicked i want to display the next image and for the left it is opposite, and if the image is the last one it should display the first image. Like a rotation of images.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a slider, no need to recreate the wheel. Use an array to index where you're at.

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

Comment: there are two div with main class, i can select the divs using querySelectorAll and run events for each instance using loop but for the images how do i select the images for each instance and run events for each group of images <div class="main">
    <img class="image" src="" alt="" />
    <img class="image" src="" alt="" />
    <button class="left">left</button><button class="right">right</button>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <img class="image" src="" alt="" />
    <img class="image" src="" alt="" />
    <button class="left">left</button><button class="right">right</button>
</div>